# processing images with .bif extension

Tags: image-processing

I am working on a medical domain project which has the initial data in the format of .bif(concerning the resolution issues) but  I am not able to process that image for further coding. Can anyone please let me know how to go about it ?

Comment: This is not a common format. Tell us the source.

Comment: It is certainly possible to reverse engineer this .bif file format. However without knowing a program that can process this kind of file format, without having the file format specification and without having some sample files it is nearly impossible to help here!

Answer (score 1):

The .bif format is produced by a Ventana medical slide scanner. https://github.com/libvips/libvips can read and convert .bif files with help from https://openslide.org/. Currently this bug causes problems with the output though: https://github.com/openslide/openslide/issues/132.

https://github.com/ome/bioformats is a Java library which also claims support for reading .bif.